# html indenting in vim

Tags: html, vim, indentation

I don't know if this is possible, but does anyone know of an indent script that will support this scenario?

(| is cursor)

given

```
<div>|<div>
```

if I press enter, I want to see

```
<div>
  |
</div>
```

instead of

```
 <div>
|<div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function! NewlineInTag()
    let lnum = getline('.')
    let cnum = col('.')

    let chars = strpart(lnum, cnum - 2, 2)
    if chars =~ '><'
        return "\<CR>\<ESC>\<UP>$o"
    else
        return "\<CR>"
    endif
endfunction

imap <CR> <C-R>=NewlineInTag()<CR>
```

Comment: ended up slightly modifying this

Answer (score 3):

delimitMate will take care of this for you.
You will however, need two additional settings...

add the >:< pair to the list of html files:

```
au FileType html let delimitMate_matchpairs = "(:),[:],{:},>:<"
```

and tell it what pattern you'd like to add after inserting a

```
au FileType html let b:delimitMate_expand_cr = "\<CR>\<CR>\<Up>\<Tab>"
```

(this will, instead of inserting two a , insert two s, press up, then insert a tab)

Comment: Note that this is probably going to be removed in future versions. See [here](http://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate/commit/89cc59821753eec21eb050ee1ba8db671deac39d#L0L331).

Comment: voted this up, but ended up going with the second answer cause of that commit

Comment: It appears this doesn't work anymore in delimitMate 2.6. The script complains about it expecting delimitMate_expand_cr to be equal to 1 or 0.

Comment: Correct. I seem to remember discussing this with the author a few years ago (or at least reading a post about it). It has since been amended to do this by default and instead requests the variable simply be set to one.

for the curious, it internally uses the pattern `<Esc>a<CR><Esc>zvO`

Answer (score 2):

Ended up going with brian Carpers answer, only modified very slightly

```
"fancy html indenting
function! NewlineInTag()
    let lnum = getline('.')
    let cnum = col('.')

    let chars = strpart(lnum, cnum - 2, 3)
    if chars =~ '></'
        return "\<CR>\<ESC>\<UP>$o"
    else
        return "\<CR>"
    endif
endfunction

autocmd FileType eruby,html imap <CR> <C-R>=NewlineInTag()<CR>
```